# stop stuck in fadeOut

Tags: jquery

I have two divs:

```
<div id="small"></div>
<div id="big"></div>
```

The small really smaller and is upside the big. z-index: 5;

The jQuery: When hover small it goes crazy, because it goes out and in of the big in a loop. So I try to stop and make sure that it stops when its fadeIn. But there is a moment if the mouse goes out fast, it fadesOut and don't fadeIn anymore. I don't understand why?

```
  $("#big").hover(function(){
        $("#small").fadeIn();
    },function(){
        $("#small").fadeOut();
    }); 

    $("#small").hover(function() {
        $("#small").fadeIn().stop();
    });
```

Comment: Could you provide a [fiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should stop it before starting to fade in:

```
 $("#small").stop().fadeIn();
```

Edit: I think that what you are really after is this code:

```
$("#big").hover(function(){
    $("#small").stop().animate({opacity: 0.0}, 1000);
},function(){
    $("#small").stop().animate({opacity: 1.0}, 1000);
}); 

$("#small").mouseover(function() {
    $("#small").stop().animate({opacity: 1.0}, 1000);
});
```

When you fade element out, its space won't be preserved and there won't be mouse events over it anymore. Instead, you can animate its opacity achieving same effect but preserving the space.

[Live test case](http://jsfiddle.net/kyPES/).

Comment: Your solution works perfect! Thank you very much.

Just for curiosity: I don't understand why my solution gets stuck sometimes? If I put the stop(); before or after the fadeIn it makes no difference.

http://jsfiddle.net/WC5Uw/

Comment: If it stops in the process of fadeIn or fadeOut, it should continue when I hover big, or not?

Comment: Cheers, glad I could help! `stop()` will stop and pending animation (fadeIn is actually animation) but it gets stuck due to infinite loop of mouse event caused somehow - not sure how though. Anyway, if this solved your case please mark this answer as Accepted by ticking the empty V icon to the left.